# Gatling AndThen after series of Injects

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling

I have a Gatling test that I would like to execute a block of set-up scenarios, then a block of scenarios for the main test, then a block of scenarios for the clean-up.

I am using AndThen but I think it is only waiting for the final scenario of the previous block to finish. It means the scenarios earlier in the block may still be running. And then the clean-up cleans up too quickly.

```
  setUp(
    initObject.createData1.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(1).during(1 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol),
    initObject.createData2.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(1).during(1 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol),
    initObject.createData3.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(1).during(1 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol)
    .andThen(
       appObject.scn1.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(1).during(1 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol),
       appObject.scn2.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(1).during(1 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol),
       appObject.scn3.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(1).during(1 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol)
       .andThen(
          cleanUpObject.deleteData1.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(1).during(1 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol),
          cleanUpObject.deleteData2.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(1).during(1 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol),
          cleanUpObject.deleteData3.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(1).during(1 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol)
      )
```

So, in the example above, clean-up might start as soon as scn3 has finished, even if scn1 and scn2 are still running.

Is there a way to get these three blocks of scenarios to run in sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I'm afraid that's not possible at the moment (as of Gatling 3.5). `andThen` lets you build a tree of scenarios while you're looking for merging tree branches.

That's an interesting feature request, though. I've opened a [ticket](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/4057) (no ETA, contributions welcome).

Answer (score 0):

If your setup, scenario and cleanup are three distinct sets, e.g. createData1, scn1 and deleteData1 form one set that is independent of the others, then you can structure your test as three concurrently running tests, each with the structure of createDataX.andThen(scnX.andThen(deleteDataX)).

So you can have

```
setUp(
    initObject.createData1.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(1).during(1 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol)
    .andThen(
       appObject.scn1.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(1).during(1 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol)
       .andThen(
          cleanUpObject.deleteData1.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(1).during(1 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol)
      )),
    initObject.createData2.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(1).during(1 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol)
    .andThen(
       appObject.scn2.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(1).during(1 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol)
       .andThen(
          cleanUpObject.deleteData2.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(1).during(1 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol)
      )),
    initObject.createData3.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(1).during(1 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol)
    .andThen(
       appObject.scn3.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(1).during(1 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol)
       .andThen(
          cleanUpObject.deleteData3.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(1).during(1 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol)
      ))
)
```